# Delegate doesn't seem to register 'params'

Tags: c#, delegates

The `params` keyword of C# allows equivalence between Array and parameter-list, does it not?

Sadly, in my implementation, this isn't the case.

```
private Entities queryType(String entitiesType, params KeyValuePair<String, object>[] values)
{
    addStandardHeaders();
    String query = parsePredicate(values);
    Task<HttpResponseMessage> filterTask = client.GetAsync(client.BaseAddress + RESTapi.ALMentitiesQuery(domain, project, entitiesType, query));
    Task.WaitAny(filterTask);
    //Callback:
    HttpResponseMessage result = filterTask.Result;
    if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        updateCookies(client.BaseAddress+RESTapi.ALMentitiesQuery(domain, project, entitiesType, query));
        mainHeaders.Clear();
        Task<Stream> output = result.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
        Task.WaitAny(output);
        //Callback:
        return (Entities)fromJSON(output.Result, typeof(Entities)); 
    }
    else
    {
        util.Exception exception = getException(result);
        throw new HttpException(exception.Title);
    }
}
```

The delegate:

```
public delegate Entities SubTypeQuery(String subType, params KeyValuePair<String, object>[] values);
```

In application:

```
public List<Run> getRuns()
{
    List<Entity> selection = ((Entities)subTypeSelector.DynamicInvoke(
        ALMObject.Run.entitiesName(),
        (new KeyValuePair<String, object>("testcycle-id", id))
    )).entities.ToList<Entity>();

    List<Run> runSet = new List<Run>();
    foreach (Entity element in selection)
        runSet.Add(new Run(element, subTypeSelector));
    return runSet;
}
```

At run-time I get a Type-Exception: "Cannot convert `KeyValuePair<String, object>` to `KeyValuePair<String, object>[]`". This renders `params` completely useless.
Suggestions?

Comment: Please reduce this to a [mcve]. Most of the code you've provided is irrelevant, and you have't told us where the problem is. Using `KeyValuePair<string, object>` instead of a simpler type also makes this more complicated than it needs to be. (I'd also strongly recommend that you start following .NET naming conventions.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you dynamically invoking? You seem to *know* the types of all the arguments.

Whats wrong with simply *calling* the delegate?

```
List<Entity> selection = ((Entities)subTypeSelector(
    ALMObject.Run.entitiesName(),
    (new KeyValuePair<String, object>("testcycle-id", id))
)).entities.ToList<Entity>();
```

Comment: My compiler angers me; it resolves that, and says 'subTypeSelector doesn't exist in this context'. Any other thoughts? @InBetween

Comment: @Olivier10178 That seems to be an unrelated issue to the question at hand and the code you've posted. Try to create a minimal repro and post a new question.

Comment: @InBtetween no wait; it says now that it's an uninvocable member.

Comment: what type should I reference the delegate as if I want to apply it?? 'Delegate' doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @Olivier10178 The type of `subTypeSelector` should be `SubTypeQuery`.

Comment: `My compiler angers me` - it is odd that when you provided the code to us originally it compiled fine, but now it complains about that line. Did you perhaps change any other parts of the code?

Answer (score 2):

> The params keyword of C# allows equivalence between Array and parameter-list, does it not?

When the C# (or VB) compiler is involved, yes. Not when you're using reflection.

The problem is that you're invoking the delegate dynamically - with reflection, basically. Reflection code *doesn't* take any notice of `params`. You either need to invoke the delegate directly (without `DynamicInvoke`) or create the array explicitly.

Comment: If the compiler says 'delegate doesn't exist in the current context' what should I do?

Comment: @Olivier10178: Without knowing what your code looks like, that doesn't really help. You might want to ask a new question with a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest changing:

```
new KeyValuePair<String, object>("testcycle-id", id)
```

to:

```
new [] { new KeyValuePair<String, object>("testcycle-id", id) }
```

See also [How do I pass an object array into a method as individual parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12167924/how-do-i-pass-an-object-array-into-a-method-as-individual-parameters) .

Comment: And how does that leverage `params` which is what the OP is asking about? If you dynamically invoke you *loose* the flexibility `params` offers. The question here is why he's dynamically invoking instead of invoking directly.

Comment: As per Jon Skeet's answer, the OP cannot make use of params in a reflection-based scenario. My answer is merely to show him / her an alternative that he / she might consider using.