# How can I pass a Parameter Array to a COM object?

Tags: .net, vba, vb.net, excel-interop

There are [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12167924/how-do-i-pass-an-object-array-into-a-method-as-individual-parameters) about passing parameter arrays and they work within managed code. When working with `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` you can run a macro in an Excel file with the `Application.Run` method. The signature of the method shows that it takes a macro name, and an arbitrary list of arguments that get passed to the Excel VBA Procedure. This looks and behaves like a Parameter array but it is not.

When you pass a parameter array to the argument section of `.Run` you get:

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'Parameter not optional.
> (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8002000F (DISP_E_PARAMNOTOPTIONAL))'

Which suggests that the Parameter Array is not getting passed correctly, likely due to COM interop not having a `ParamArray` type.

How would I expand my arbitrary length `ParamArray` into an arbitrary list of arguments that can be passed to the COM object?

EXAMPLE CODE:

```
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Run an Excel macro silently in the background. Quits at the end.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="excelFileName">Full path to Excel file.</param>
    ''' <param name="macroName">The macro you want to run.</param>
    ''' <param name="args">Arguments to pass into that macro procedure.</param>
    Public Shared Sub RunMacro(excelFileName As String, macroName As String, ParamArray args As String())
        ' Create new Excel instance
        Dim excelApp = New Application With {
            .Visible = True,
            .EnableEvents = False   ' Suppress the Workbook_Open event
        }

        Dim excelBooks As Workbooks = excelApp.Workbooks

        ' Open the Excel workbook
        Dim thisWorkbook As Workbook = excelBooks.Open(excelFileName)

        ' Hide the window while the macro runs
        excelApp.Visible = False

        ' Run the VBA procedure.
        excelApp.Run(macroName, args)  ' <-- Throws because it can't accept ParamArray

        ' Cleanup
        thisWorkbook.Close(SaveChanges:=False)
        excelApp.Quit()
    End Sub
```

Comment: This is a point I've raised in discussions for twinBasic.  VBA cannot forward a ParamArray as a list of item.  To meet the needs of Application run, you will need to deconstruct your param array.

Comment: How about one of the solutions here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20783170/pass-array-to-paramarray  Don't know how/if they translate to .Net...

Comment: @TimWilliams, I saw that before. That's for unboxing and not for passing to COM.

Comment: I cannot understand what you try accomplishing... If you try calling a `Sub`/`Function` named as `macroName` having a single `ParamArray()` parameter, **you cannot call it passing an array**. Even if you pseudo declare it as `ParamArray()`. **Not only through a COM interop**. **You cannot do it in Excel VBA, neither**. In VBA, `ParamArray()` is used only to pass an undefined number of parameters/types. But **you must call the function using all these parameters**!. If you want passing an array, do it, **but not declaring as 'ParamArray()` and declaring in the called sub `arr () As Variant`**.

Comment: In conclusion, Excel (VBA, COM, whatever) uses, admits a `ParamArray()` **only as a called Sub/function last parameter**. And does that only to allow an undefined number of arguments/types when make the call, as stated above... Please, see [here](https://bettersolutions.com/vba/arrays/paramarray.htm)...

Comment: @FaneDuru For you to understand what I'm doing you would have to know what the signature of `Application.Run` is. The documentation says it can take 0-30 arguments much like a ParameterArray would.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Application.Run

Comment: Yes, this is its definition. But i suggested above a simpler way, which looks to not be understood... If you use `args As Variant` and not use anymore  `Sub macroName(ParamArray() As Variant)`. If you use `Sub macroName(arrP As Variant)` you can pass the whole `args` array as large as you need and process it in Excel workbook procedure **as you want**...

Comment: I was attempting to write a wrapper that matched the signature of `Application.Run` and I eventually did. I think what you are suggesting requires a modification of the VBA code, where what I am doing will work with *any* Excel macro.

Comment: In VBA you would call it as `Application Run "WorkbookName!macroName", args`. Convert and use it calling through COM and it will work. Now I need to close my laptop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer I found is often the case when facing an unpossible situation. "Don't do that".

The interop method of `.Run` won't take a `ParameterArray` and there is no way to dynamically pass arguments. So we need a different method. In the case of COM interop you can manually `.InvokeMember` which accepts parameters as an array of objects. This gets us around the fact that the `.Run` takes one mandatory string and up to 30 arguments by allowing us to pass it all at once as an array.

Final method looks like this:

```
''' <summary>
''' Run an Excel macro silently in the background. Quits at the end.
''' </summary>
''' <param name="excelFileName">Full path to Excel file.</param>
''' <param name="macroName">The macro you want to run.</param>
''' <param name="args">Arguments to pass into that macro procedure.</param>
Public Shared Sub RunMacro(excelFileName As String, macroName As String, ParamArray args As String())

    ' Make an array of object of string for the invoker
    Dim argumentArray = args.ToArray()
    Dim objectArray = New Object(argumentArray.Length) {}
    objectArray(0) = macroName
    If argumentArray IsNot Nothing Then argumentArray.CopyTo(objectArray, 1)

    Dim excelApp As Application = Nothing
    Dim excelBooks As Workbooks = Nothing
    Dim thisWorkbook As Workbook = Nothing
    Try
        ' Create new Excel instance
        excelApp = New Application With {
            .Visible = False,       ' Hide the window while the macro runs
            .EnableEvents = False   ' Suppress the Workbook_Open event
        }

        ' Open the Excel workbook
        excelBooks = excelApp.Workbooks
        thisWorkbook = excelBooks.Open(excelFileName)
        excelApp.GetType().InvokeMember(
        "Run", Reflection.BindingFlags.Default Or Reflection.BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, Nothing, excelApp, objectArray
        )
    Finally ' Cleanup
        If thisWorkbook IsNot Nothing Then
            thisWorkbook.Close(SaveChanges:=False)
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(thisWorkbook)
        End If

        If excelBooks IsNot Nothing Then Marshal.ReleaseComObject(excelBooks)

        If excelApp IsNot Nothing Then
            excelApp.Quit()
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(excelApp)
        End If
    End Try
End Sub
```